# How to select columns which has different value from two table?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables which are having same columns
ex, Table A and Table B

Table A:

```
Name  Address   Phone
A     Add1      123
```

Table B:

```
Name  Address   Phone
A     Add1      12345
```

i want to select only column which has different value

Expected Output:

```
Phone
123
1234
```

Comment: I think dynamic SQL is going to be the way to go for you. What have you tried?

Comment: Not sure how you are even getting `1234` considering you wrote that there are 2 values across the tables and that is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Phones.Phone
FROM A
INNER JOIN b ON A.Name = B.Name AND A.Addr = B.Addr AND A.Phone <> B.Phone
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT Phone = A.Phone
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Phone = B.Phone
) AS Phones
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].